# How can I have a datatable detect multiple columns when iterating through rows in C# with conditionals?

Tags: c#, datatables, iteration, rows

I am new to C# and I have to rebuild a JavaScript program into C#.

This program involves reading a CSV file and iterating through it to detect different values and to produce outputs.

Here is an example of my code:

```
foreach(DataRow row in results.Rows)
{
    if (row["Date"].ToString().Substring(row["Date"].ToString().Length - 16) == "2021 12:00:00 AM") //Checks if the year is 2021 or not in the "date" column
    {
        if (row["State"].ToString() == "CA") //Looks for CA state in the "state" column, however, it appears to not be finding it?
        { //DOES NEEDED CALCULATIONS
```

Basically, the code detects the "2021" date just fine in the data table, but it can't find the CA state at all when iterating through the rows, therefore, the required calculations are never done.

Here is what the data table looks like:
[DataTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1grp.png)

Help is greatly appreciated, I been stuck on this for a while due to my lack of knowledge with C#.

Comment: `This program involves reading a CSV file and iterating through it to detect different values` is there a reason why you're not using a dedicated parser for this? For example, something like [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/). On another point assign `row["State"].ToString()` to a local var, what's the value, is it what you expect? If not, are there spaces, maybe you need to trim them if so? There can be many reasons for this, but it's a guessing game for us especially if we don't have [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: My advice is not to work on DateTime object using string.

Comment: @zaggler I already have the CSV file read and stored in a datatable. Is there a better way to do this? I am almost completely new to C#

Comment: `CSV file read and stored in a datatable` why are you doing this? Create classes that represent your data and use them instead.

Comment: @EKOlog How could I find date then? Visual studio produces an error if I try (row["Date"] and it says I need to convert it to ToString even though that column was created in the first place to be a DateTime object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Odds are that there is some extra whitespace in `row["State"]`

Try this:

```
foreach(DataRow row in results.Rows)
{
    if (row["Date"].ToString().Substring(row["Date"].ToString().Length - 16) == "2021 12:00:00 AM") //Checks if the year is 2021 or not in the "date" column
    {
        if (row["State"].ToString().Contains("CA")) //Looks for CA state in the "state" column, however, it appears to not be finding it?
        { //DOES NEEDED CALCULATIONS
```

That being said, all the previous comments are really helpful for your needs.  Don't do your own CSV parsing if you don't have to. Don't work on `DateTime` as `string`. Make your own DTOs to represent records, instead of using `DataTable`.

Example:

```
record Invoice
{
    public int InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}

public void DoStuff()
{
    var invoices = ReadInvoiceFile("Your/Path/Here.csv");
    foreach (var invoice in invoices)
    {
        if(invoice.Date.Year != 2021) continue;
        if (invoice.State.Contains("CA"))
        {
            //do CA specific stuff here
        }
    }
}

private List<Invoice> ReadInvoiceFile(string path)
{
    //realistically you would use a 3rd party library to do this
}
```

I would also add that you shouldn't be using inline literals in your code (such as `2021` or `"CA"` in my example). And making your behavior depend on an if statement around a hardcoded state and year violates the Open-Closed principle, and a good candidate for refactoring into a factory method. But lets take one step at a time.

Comment: @hidden82 You're welcome. Please see the updated answer for some additional code improvements

Comment: I wish I could but I need at least 15 reputation for that, it says the feedback was recorded though? I just made this account for help -- once I get the reputation I'll upvote you!

Comment: I wanna try to do it the way you did in your example -- this may take a little bit more learning for me, like 3rd party libraries and stuff -  but that definitely looks much better than whatever I was trying to do